# How to remove comma from eachline of a csv file using java

Tags: java

Remove the comma from end of ecah line of a csv file using java
Ex:
"A","B","C","D","E",""
I need till "E"

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure, but I think you can achive that by using a Buffered Reader. Then you save the text as a result. Now you can cut out the comma's and put it back in using the BufferedWriter

Comment: but its not acheving.

Comment: As I said, Im not quite sure about it. And since you dont show us what you "tried" I could not know that. It was just an idea. If it does not work maybe someone else has a better idea.